# How to make frontend Docker container find backend container ip?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm building a website using a [Django backend](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and a [Vuejs frontend](https://vuejs.org/). I develop using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which works great. The only thing is that my frontend needs to call the backend container, which I currently do by hardcoding the container ip address in the Javascript:

```
const API_HOST = '192.168.0.105';
const API_ADDRESS = `http://${COCKPIT_SERVER_HOST}:8000/cockpit`;
```

This works, but it's obviously not the right way to do it. Sometimes the ip address of the backend container changes which makes me lookup the new ip address again.

In my `docker-compose.yml` file I named the backend `api` (I pasted my docker-compose file below). But if I define `API_HOST` in the Javascript as

```
const API_HOST = 'api';
```

it obviously doesn't work because that is called from within the browser, which is unaware of the Docker network.

How can I make the frontend always call the correct backend, without the need to constantly lookup the container ip address?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: cockpit
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  api:
    build: server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >
      bash -c '
      python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
  frontend:
    build: client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Comment: As you point out, the request is coming from the client's browser; the fact that Docker's involved is irrelevant. The simplest option is often to have the backend serve the built frontend in production, so that it can make relative requests and doesn't need configuring.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Yes, that makes sense. But what would then be an easy way to do this while devving? I guess this is a very common pattern so I presume there's an easy solution for it..

Comment: In dev you use a proxy to achieve the same thing; client makes (again, relative) requests to e.g. webpack dev server, which proxies to the backend.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Ok, that sounds like something that could work. Do you have a link to some tutorial about this? I can't really find anything. I guess I'm looking for the wrong words..

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to narrow it down that far, and tutorial requests are off topic here. I'd search for "{front end framework} dev proxy" or similar.

Comment: Just setup a webserver, ngnix or similar.  Or maybe better seen as your using node using something like serve. https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

Answer (score 0):

I would consider 2 solutions:

**1. Static IP addresses**
In docker-compose you can assign static IPs for each service.
*Pros: Easy to implement*
*Cons: Hardcoded IP adresses in your code*

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: cockpit
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.2.1
  api:
    build: server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >
      bash -c '
      python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.2.2
  frontend:
    build: client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.2.3

networks:
  test:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

**2. Reverse proxy**
As Keith suggested you can setup a reverse proxy (via ngnix or similar) to resolve your calls to services.
*Pros: Good approach with no hardcoding*
*Cons: Additional service in your compose file*